# How can I get rid of this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch weather data from open meteo API, I want to access the daily time from API, it is showing daily time on page first time. After that when I reload it is giving me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'time')

Below is my code:

```html
import  { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Button from "./Button";
import Card from "./Card";
import Card2 from "./Card2";
import axios from "axios";




const Infopage =()=>{
  const [myData,setMyData]=useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get("https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,apparent_temperature,precipitation,rain,showers,snowfall,weathercode,pressure_msl,visibility,windspeed_10m,temperature_80m,temperature_120m,temperature_180m&daily=weathercode,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,apparent_temperature_max,apparent_temperature_min,sunrise,sunset,uv_index_max,precipitation_sum,showers_sum,snowfall_sum,precipitation_hours,windspeed_10m_max,windgusts_10m_max&current_weather=true&timeformat=unixtime&timezone=GMT").then((res)=> setMyData(res.data)).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        });
    },[])

    return(<>
    <div className="bg-dark"> 
    <button className=" bg-white  h-[2rem] w-[2rem] p-1 rounded-full top-3 m-5 absolute right-[10rem]"> </button>
    <button className=" bg-grey  h-[2rem] w-[2rem] p-1 rounded-full top-3 m-5 absolute right-[6rem]"> </button>
    <div className=" mt-[5rem] ml-[10rem]"> 
    
    <Card time={myData.daily.time[0]} />
    
       
     
    </div>
    <h1 className="text-white mt-[1rem] ml-[10rem]">Today's Highlight </h1>
    <Card2/>
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    </>)
}
export default Infopage;
```

Comment: How do you update the myData variable?

Comment: `myData` is an (empty) array.  (And then later, on another render, gets updated to something else that we don't know.)  Arrays have no property called `daily`.  It's not clear what you're *expecting* that operation to do.

Answer (score 2):

On the initial render, the effect has not been run yet, so `myData` is an empty array with no data. It does not have a `daily` property. You need to handle this case; for instance, you could render a loading message instead.

```
const [myData,setMyData] = useState(); 
// make undefined initially so it's simpler to check if there is data

// other code...
return <>
    {/*...*/}
    {myData ? <Card time={myData.daily.time[0]} /> : "Loading data..."}
</>;
```

Comment: after writing myData.daily instead of just  writing myData in conditional statement. I got rid of this error. Thank you !

Comment: @ShefaliKanaujia Happy to help. You would be able to directly use `myData` in the conditional if you changed the useState as shown in my answer to `const [myData,setMyData] = useState();`.